# SQL code using case criteria however unable to run

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio. Where have I gone wrong?

Here is what I want to do - I want to get a value:

- If duration in months between `exstart_start` and `dateord` is <= 0, then

  - (minus 24 months from duration of `exstart_start` to `datecoms` ie only if the solution is >=0
  - (if the above is not satisfied then minus 12 months from duration of `exstart_start` to `datecoms` ie only if the solution is >= 0
  - If none are satisfied than make it 0
- If duration in months between `exstart_start` and `dateord` is > 0, then make it equal to duration in months between `exstart_start` and `dateord`

My attempt at the `CASE`:

```
CASE 
    WHEN DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, dateord) <= 0
        THEN
            (CASE 
                 WHEN ((DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)) - 24 <= 0) 
                     THEN 0 
                     ELSE (DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)) - 24 
             END)
        ELSE
            ((CASE 
                  WHEN DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)) - 12 <= 0) 
                      THEN 0 
                      ELSE (DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)) - 12) 
              END) 
       END)

ELSE 
    DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, dateord) END AS diffexstarttoordered
```

Comment: Edit your question and instead of LINE1, LINE2, format your question using ```, the same way you've formatted the block of code at the start. That way we can read your question and also copy-paste if we try to recreate your problem. Also, in order for us to know how to help you need to explain what you want and also give us the result of what you're trying.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with expected result from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starter i think there is 1 END too much or 1 CASE less because we got 4 END and 2 ELSE for 1 CASE:

```
CASE --1.
WHEN DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, dateord) <= 0
    THEN
-- ? here might be missing a CASE
        (CASE --2.
             WHEN ((DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)) - 24 <= 0) 
                 THEN 0 
                 ELSE (DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)) - 24 
         END --2.)
    ELSE --(1 else from first case)
        ((CASE --3.
              WHEN DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)) - 12 <= 0) 
                  THEN 0 
                  ELSE (DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)) - 12) 
          END--3.) 
   END --?)
ELSE(--? else from 1.CASE if 1 CASE is missing or too much)
  DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, dateord) 
END --1.) 
AS diffexstarttoordered
```

update:
After some thinking this might be your desired solution:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, dateord)<=0
 THEN
 (CASE WHEN ((DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)-24) >=0) 
                  THEN (DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)-24)
       WHEN ((DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)-12) >=0)
                  THEN (DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, datecoms)-12)
       ELSE 0           
  END) 
ELSE DATEDIFF (m, exstart_start, dateord) 
END AS diffexstarttoordered
```

Comment: good to hear :)